Magento 2.4.7 When uploading a GIF image of a product, it is converted into PNG format
Product GIF image uploads in Magento 2.4.6 but not working in Magento 2.4.7
Error Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/1qWandr.png

this is not compatible with the Magento 2.4.7 version. To avail the same, need to integrate 3rd party extensions available.
